# В чем некорректность js-скрипта?

Tags: javascript

Подключил скрипт на сайт, но плавной прокрутки нет. Однако на аналогичном wordpress сайте все работает нормально, хотя версии темы разные.
ссылка сайта: http://xxxzeio5.beget.tech
Код подключения Скролла:

```
jQuery(function($) { 

$('a[href^="#"]').live('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target_offset = $(this.hash).offset() ? $(this.hash).offset().top : 0;
    //change this number to create the additional off set        
    var customoffset = 85;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset - customoffset}, 500);
});

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Открывайте инструменты разработчика, смотрите ошибки

Comment: @Crantisz, ошибок нет, ошибка в самом js

Comment: ну почините тогда js!

Comment: @OlmerDale, спасибо за конструктивный ответ!

Comment: Ошибок то и правда нет http://prntscr.com/euszjc

Comment: @Рашен Беар, перейдите на сайт скролл ведь не плавный, он мгновенно переходит. Хотя на таком же сайте (версия темы более старая) скролл плавный